# Can you initialise a Guid with a string null

Tags: c#, .net

It's not a pressing issue but I would like to know if there's a way to initialise a Guid like this:

```
  string input = "example text...";
  Guid? outputGuid;                                       
  outputGuid = new Guid( ExampleMethodToGetString(input) ?? null );
```

Though this doesn't error, it will not run, this obviously because overloads don't work this way, just wondering if there's anything shorter than below. The current working solution is this:

```
  string input = "example text...";
  Guid? outputGuid;
  input = ExampleMethodToGetString( input );
  outputGuid = input == null ? (Guid?) null : new Guid( input );
```

Comment: `something ?? null` is redundant.

Comment: @Whelkaholism if the string is null, I'd like to make the Guid null

Comment: Do you really need a nullable Guid? Perhaps you can use `Guid.Empty` instead?

Comment: I find Nullable values always a pain, how do you tell apart null through error from null with intend? If the Guid is optional I would either try to move closer to where you are going to use/pass the guid and pass null instead or use the null object pattern to ensure the ability to differentiate between null by intend and null by error. - Not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: @Peter why not use [Guid.Empty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.empty(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of null?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way

```
string input = "example text...";
Guid? outputGuid = null;
input = ExampleMethodToGetString( input );
if(input != null)
{
    outputGuid = new Guid( input );
}
```

Comment: @Peter Did you solve the problem? Please accept the answer if it was helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no pre-built solution to this.

What about an extension method ?

```
public static Guid? ToGuidOrNull(this string str)
{
    Guid guid = default(Guid);
    if (Guid.TryParse(str, out guid))
    {
        return (Guid?)guid;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

EDIT thanks to **@Matthew Watson** suggestions

```
public static Guid? ParseToNullableGuid(string str)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) return null;
    Guid guid = Guid.Parse(str); // Will throw if not a valid Guid
    return (Guid?)guid;
}
```

Comment: That really doesn't look general enough to use as an extension method for string...

Comment: @MatthewWatson If he puts it in it's own namespace, and only includes that namespace in classes which will use this, why would this be a problem?

Comment: @RB You should [use extension methods sparingly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524599/what-is-the-motivation-behind-use-extension-methods-sparingly). In this case, there's no compelling reason to make this an extension method rather than a normal method.

Comment: This code will cause invalid GUID strings to produce the same result as a null - I'm not sure that's a good idea. Also, since `guid` is being initialised via `out` there's no need to initialise it beforehand.

Comment: However, the idea of writing a method to encapsulate the logic is sound, just not as an extension method.

Comment: Updated my answer to follow your suggestion @Matthew Watson

Answer (score 1):

Why not make a static method out of the last line:

```
 public static Guid? GetGuidOrNull(string str)
 {
    return str == null ? (Guid?)null : new Guid(str);
 }
```

Or even:

```
 public static Guid? GetGuidOrNull(string str)
 {
    str = MethodToGetString(str);
    return str == null ? (Guid?)null : new Guid(str);
 }
```

Then you can just do (first case):

```
 string input = "example text...";
 Guid? outputGuid = GetGuidOrNull(MethodToGetString(input));
```

Or (second case):

```
 string input = "example text...";
 Guid? outputGuid = GetGuidOrNull(input);
```